# Matlab, Mex files, undefined functions

Tags: matlab, mex

It may seem like this question has been asked already, but after several days of dealing with this problem and searching for solutions, I am coming up empty. To begin, I am using matlab2012a

So I have the mexa64 file compiled, let's call it foo.mexa64 .  My computer can handle 64 bit (matlab >>computer, returns GLNXA64).  I have added the folder that foo.mexa64 is in to the path using the pathtool. I did this when I opened matlab, so the changes are there. This is also not in the root/toolbox folder, it is saved in my Documents/MATLAB.../fooDirectory folder.

I can run these mex files in the command line in a different directory and everything works fine. However I cannot call them in a function, I get the "Undefined function 'foo' for input arguments of type 'double'" error.

Using the 'which foo' function returns the path:
home/.../Documents/MATLAB/.../fooDirectory/foo.mexa64

'help foo' returns 
foo not found

To check, I created a dummy.m file in the fooDirectory folder. This function can be run in other functions outside of the directory with no issue.

If you need anything else, please let me know, I am completely at a loss!

Comment: Hmm... My approach would be to put a `keyboard` right before the `foo` function call and try your `which foo` and `exist('foo')` there, in that outer function.

Comment: I did not know about the 'keyboard' command, thank you! This was very helpful, helped me find the folder issue!